# solr facet !tag on multiple columns

Tags: solr

I know this is possible in Solr which do the grouping irrespective of one values.
i.e below line do the grouping based on column1 considering all filters except the column column1

`&facet.field={!ex=column1}column1`

now i wana know can i do the grouping in which i consider all filters except two filters say column1,colun2

like

`&facet.field={!ex=column1 !ex=column2}column1`

however above is not working.

Pleas help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters) it says :

> Both the tag and **ex** local params may specify multiple values by
>   separating them with commas.

So, it should be look like :

```
&facet.field={!ex=column1,column2}column1
```

I didn't try it but think that it will work.

Comment: select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.zeros=false&fq=column1:(16 31)&&fq=COLUMN2:(6 208)&fq={!tag=COLUMN2,column1}COLUMN2:(6)&facet.field={!ex=COLUMN2,column1}COLUMN2&start=0&rows=0

this is not working

Comment: you should add !tag for each column

Answer (score 0):

&fq={!tag=COLUMN2,column1}column1:(16 31)&fq={!tag=COLUMN2,column1}COLUMN2:(6)&facet.field={!ex=COLUMN2,column1}COLUMN2